# Azure Monitor (Application Insights) log queries charts - what is on Y-axis?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

How to choose what is shown on Y-axis in Application Insights (Azure Monitor?) chart?
[image]

I have custom events in Application Insights and I want to build a time-series chart with a custom metric.

But instead of my metric an itemCount is shown on Y-axis. How to choose a metric for Y-axis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to getting your time-series charts right is to fetch all the time and metric information in the result set from your query.

Considering the `requests` table as an example (you can apply it to your `customEvents` data as appropriate):

```
# Simple time-series chart
requests
| summarize Requests = count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Output:
[image: Simple time-series chart]
Here, the query control uses timestamp for the X-axis and Requests for the Y-axis.

Next, multiple metrics can also be plotted as:

```
# Time-series chart with multiple metrics
requests
| summarize Requests = count(), Users = dcount(user_Id) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Output:
[image: Plot multiple metrics]
The query control uses timestamp for the X-axis and Requests & Users as separate series on the Y-axis here.

There is also the `make-series` operator, which has the option to provide default values for empty buckets.

```
requests
| where name contains "POST"
| make-series Requests = count() default = 0 on timestamp from ago(1d) to now() step 1h by RequestName = name
| render timechart
```

Output:
[image: make-series operator]

For additional reading, please refer to the following resources:

- [Chart visualizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-chart-visualizations)
- [Creating charts and diagrams from Azure Monitor log queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts)
- [make-series operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator)